# Ajax always returning 0

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

My AJAX post always returns 0 and I have no idea why
PHP

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enable_signup_scripts');
function enable_signup_scripts () {
   wp_enqueue_script('signup',get_template_directory_uri().'/signup/script.js' , array('jquery'));
   wp_localize_script('signup', 'daten', array('ajaxurl' =>  admin_url("admin-ajax.php", null)));
};
add_action('wp_ajax_createuser','createuser');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_createuser','createuser');
function createuser () {echo 'hello';};
```

Script.js

```
$.post(
   daten.ajaxurl,
   {
      "action": "createuser",
   }, 
   function(data){
       alert(data)
   }
)
```

Does anyone know the issue?

Comment: [Docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) say `Additionally, if the request succeeds, but the Ajax action does not match a WordPress hook defined with add_action('wp_ajax_(action)', ...) or add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)', ...), then admin-ajax.php will respond 0.`  Is the add_action happening for every request?

Comment: @drew010 I've copied the ajax action to a plugin and it worked. Do you know if it's possible to make them work in a theme?

Comment: @MichaelCool, yes you can define this hook inside your theme's functions.php.

Comment: @MahaDev how can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the wp_die() function in your code, wp_die() is compulsory use like below code.

```
function createuser () {
  echo 'hello';
  wp_die();
  };
```

Comment: I've copied the ajax action to a plugin and it worked. Do you know if it's possible to make them work in a theme?

Comment: I don't think `wp_die();` is compulsory for wordpress ajax